# Linux kernel function 'lookup_page_ext' returning NULL

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am new to Linux kernel programming. I am writing a kernel module for Linux kernel-6.0

Here is the below code

```c
static int count_wired_pages(unsigned long start_pfn, unsigned long end_pfn)
{
    unsigned long pfn;
    int nr_pages=0, page_mt, count = 0;
    struct page *page;
    struct page_ext *page_ext;
    struct page_owner *page_owner;

    for (pfn = start_pfn; pfn < end_pfn; pfn++) {
        if (!pfn_valid(pfn))
            continue;
        /*some code*/

        page = pfn_to_page(pfn);
        page_ext = lookup_page_ext(page);
        if (unlikely(!page_ext))
            continue;

        if (!test_bit(PAGE_EXT_OWNER_ALLOCATED, &page_ext->flags))
            continue;

        page_owner = get_page_owner(page_ext);
        page_mt = gfp_migratetype(page_owner->gfp_mask);
        nr_pages = (1UL << page_owner->order);
        
        /*some code*/

}
```

In the above code, I am calling the function `lookup_page_ext()`. In the kernel `.config` file, I have enabled `CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION` and `CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER`. Also, I have added `EXPORT_SYMBOL` to function `lookup_page_ext()` so that it is visible to my module.

In spite of doing all this, the function is returning `NULL`. Is there something that I am missing?